# Who investigates the Kidnapped Sheriff?

Tags: colorado, investigation, fbi, kidnapping

Assume the mob kidnaps the sheriff of a county of Colorado ([18 USC 351](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/351) does not apply to the Sheriff, right?) and they never cross the state border. During the kidnapping, the mob's enforcers wound a deputy of the sheriff, but he survives (so [28 USC 540](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/28/540) doesn't apply, right?).

Who is responsible for investigating this: FBI, Colorado State Police, or the Sheriff's department?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because kidnapping is a violation of state law, the Colorado Bureau of Investigation would have [jurisdiction to investigate](http://24-33.5-409). Assuming the crime occurred in the sheriff's home county, [the undersheriff](https://codes.findlaw.com/co/title-30-government-county/co-rev-st-sect-30-10-505.html) would take over and could also investigate.

And if the sheriff is missing for more than 24 hours, federal law assumes that he was kidnapped [using the instrumentalities of state commerce](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/1201), giving the FBI jurisdiction to investigate, as well. Even before 24 hours, the fact that the mob acts as part of a criminal enterprise with an effect on interstate commerce, would also give the FBI jurisdiction to investigate under [RICO](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/part-I/chapter-96).

Comment: FWIW, after the undersheriff, the coroner steps in to fill the sheriff's shoes.

Answer (score 1):

The FBI doesn't sit around waiting for other agencies to prove beyond a reasonable doubt that the FBI has jurisdiction.   The FBI is allowed to be proactive: they have every right to investigate *whether* a case falls in their jurisdiction.  Of course, that involves the same sleuthing needed to solve the case itself.

As an example, the FBI did respond to the [2007 Boston Mooninite Invasion](https://www.boston.com/news/local-news/2017/01/31/looking-back-at-the-boston-mooninite-panic-10-years-later)... They turned out not to be a crime in the FBI's jurisdiction, or even a crime of any size at all.